# Opening SQLite3 in different files?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, discord.js

I'm making a discordbot and I'm using sqlite3 as database. I created a Database in my Bot.JS file but I'm trying to acces it in a different file how would I do that?
This is the database

```
db.serialize(function() {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (lang TEXT)");

    var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
    stmt.run('nl');
    stmt.finalize();

    db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, lang FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
        var lang = row.lang;
    });
});
```

And this is how I tried it but didn't work

```
if(cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args, chalk, succes, error, lang, db);
```

Thanks already :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it to the run function, just create a sub-variable of the bot variable. So after you init the DB, place this line of code; `bot.db = db;` Then in the other files to access the database use the variable `bot.db`. (eg. `db.each()` would be `bot.db.each()` in other files.) You can do this with other variables as well such as lang, error, chalk, and success (Just replace where it says db with the variable).